# External moment over an hinge

Tags: statics, moments

I want to find the moments around points A and B in the following figure.
Suppose the structure is fixed at the point where $F_{ax}$ and $F_{ay}$ are located.
I consider A and B to be hinges so that the rigid links can rotate.

Is it plausible to calculate the external moment at points A and B with respect to the external forces, such that the structure remains in equilibrium?

I know that the moments in hinges are 0, but would external moments keep the structure in equilibrium?

[image]

Comment: If it's fixed at the bottom point, teh bottom member, Fay and Fax are irrelevant - you may as well just start with a pinned supprot at A. ARe youre three F.Ts supposed to be equal magnitude? Are they at defined positions and angles? If so, it seems like simple algebra.

Comment: @achrn Yes, the $F_T$ forces are of equal magnitude with a given position and angle. So the moments in A and B can simply be calculated as the distance to the forces times the force and sin() of the angle between them?

Comment: Understanding the purpose of this structure might help with the answer? Is it some sort of robotic arm? Are you trying to calculate the torque required for a motor at A and B?

Comment: @NMech This is a model I did of a human lower leg where point A represents the ankle joint and point B represents the knee joint. My goal is to estimate the joint moments based on these external $F_T$ forces.

Comment: @lookingforananswer then in that case, if the person is standing and the foot is actively engaged, you'd need to have the x-position of the weight of the body and the weight in order to calculate the A and B moments. Try it yourself, when you bend your knee and try to shift your weight back and forth, the joints experiences different loads.